# Source of illegal immigrants to the US over the years

Tags: data-request, demographics

Would like to find a source, that shows or estimates the numbers of illegal immigrants entering the US broken down by their country of origin, each year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ctrl + f on this page

http://www.dhs.gov/immigration-statistics-publications

for the text `unauthorized`